# Script not overriding theme script despite running after

Tags: jquery, wordpress

On our site, http://darealty.com/aurum/location the height of each section is being set by the Wordpress theme I'm using so that it's effectively as high as the window size.

I'm using jQuery to override this height of each section (I can go into why but it's not really relevant to the question).

My problem is that it doesn't allow me to override the height being set by the theme javascript, even though I've made sure that my script is loaded AFTER the theme. (I manually put it in the footer and I enqueued it in functions.php).

The only way I could get it to actually work is to use setTimeout to delay execution of my script.

Newbie questions:

1) Will whichever script runs last always have the say in what height is being applied, or is there something else to consider?

2) Does that mean that my script is NOT being executed after the theme script, despite what I think?

3) Is there a better way I can ensure that my script runs last?

Here is my code, apologies if it's a bit messy:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  "use strict";
  if($(window).width() >= 768) {
  $( ".left-text" ).each(function() {
   
   var windowHeight = $( window ).height();
   var leftTextHeight = $(this).height();
   var sectionHeight = $(this).parents(".highlight-left").height();  
   var desktopLogoHeight= $(".desktop-logo").height(); 
   var sectionWrapperPaddingTop = $(this).parents(".section_wrapper").css("padding-top"); 
   sectionWrapperPaddingTop = parseInt(sectionWrapperPaddingTop);
   var sectionWrapperPaddingBottom = $(this).parents(".section_wrapper").css("padding-bottom"); 
   sectionWrapperPaddingBottom = parseInt(sectionWrapperPaddingBottom);
   
   var t = $(this); // make 'this' a variable so we can use it inside the compareHeight function
   
   function compareHeight() {
    var difference = windowHeight - desktopLogoHeight - leftTextHeight - sectionWrapperPaddingBottom;
     if ( difference < 0 ) {
     console.log("Difference " + difference);
     console.log("Increase margin: YES");        
     
     var increaseMarginAmount = desktopLogoHeight - sectionWrapperPaddingTop;
     
     // Set margin on left-text and increase height     
     
     $(t).css("margin-top", increaseMarginAmount);           
     
     // Set section height equal to original height + left text margin-top height
         
     $(t).parents(".highlight-left").height(sectionHeight + increaseMarginAmount + 33);            
     }
     else {
      console.log("Difference :" + difference);
      console.log("Increase margin: NO");
     }
   }
   
   setTimeout(function(){ compareHeight(); }, 2000);
  
  });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.